# java.io.InvalidClassException: weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging; class incompatible

Tags: java, serialization, io, weka, feature-extraction

I am trying to develop a program that automatically detects mood of the song. I transfered my project from one laptop to another. completed there and there is an error which keeps coming up. Have searched a lot yet found no solution. 
here is the code where the problem persists.
    package featureExtractor;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.io.ObjectStreamClass;
import java.nio.file.CopyOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

import ui.Test;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.gui.Main;
import weka.gui.visualize.VisualizePanel;


public class Classify{
static String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
private static String happy = curDir+"\\Playlists\\Happy";
private static String rel = curDir+"\\Playlists\\Relaxed";
private static String rom = curDir+"\\Playlists\\Romantic";
private static String sad = curDir+"\\Playlists\\Sad";


private static Test aa ;
public static String[] mood;
static CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
        StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
}; 

public Classify(Test test) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Classify.aa=test;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{


    Icon icon=null;
    Path original = Paths.get(aa.getFile().getAbsolutePath());

    File file = new File(aa.getFile().getAbsolutePath());

    System.out.println("Classifying");



    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

    Instances data = new Instances(reader);
    reader.close();

    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);

    Classifier cls = (Classifier)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(curDir+"/src/resources/MetaBag.model");
    mood = new String[data.numInstances()];
    if(data.numInstances()==1)
    {
        double b = cls.classifyInstance((data.instance(0)));
        Attribute a1 = data.classAttribute();
        String moodSin = a1.value((int) b);

        switch(moodSin)
        {
        case "Happy":
            icon = (Icon)(new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/happy.png")));
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(original,Paths.get(happy+"/"+file.getName()), options);
            break;
        case "Romantic":
            icon = (Icon)new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/rom.jpg"));
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(original,Paths.get(rom+"/"+file.getName()), options);
            break;
        case "Sad":
            icon = (Icon)new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/sad.png"));
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(original,Paths.get(sad+"/"+file.getName()), options);
            break;
        case "Relaxed":
            icon = (Icon)new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/relaxed.png"));
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(original,Paths.get(rel+"/"+file.getName()), options);

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Main.getFrames())[0], "The Mood of the song is " +moodSin, "And the Mood is", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);

    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<data.numInstances();i++)
        {

            double b = cls.classifyInstance((data.instance(i)));
            Attribute a1 = data.classAttribute();
            mood[i] = a1.value((int) b);
            updateDisplay(i,mood[i]);       
        }

        makePlaylist();


    }
}

public static void updateDisplay(int i,String mood)
{
    String temp = aa.getFileNames()[i];
    aa.getTextArea().append((i+1)+ ". "+ temp +" - "+ mood+System.getProperty("line.separator"));

}

public static void makePlaylist()
{   String[] temp = aa.getFileNames();
    aa.getTextArea().append("Creating Playlist"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
for(int i=0;i<aa.getFileNames().length;i++)
{
    try
    {
        switch(mood[i])
        {
        case "Happy":
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(Paths.get(temp[i]),Paths.get(happy+"/"+new File(temp[i]).getName()), options);
            break;
        case "Romantic":
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(Paths.get(temp[i]),Paths.get(rom+"/"+new File(temp[i]).getName()), options);
            break;
        case "Sad":
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(Paths.get(temp[i]),Paths.get(sad+"/"+new File(temp[i]).getName()), options);
            break;
        case "Relaxed":
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(Paths.get(temp[i]),Paths.get(rel+"/"+new File(temp[i]).getName()), options);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
aa.getTextArea().append("Playlist Created"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Main.getFrames())[0], "Playlist Created. Please check the Progress Box for the results", "All Done!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null );
}
```

}

And here is the error.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5178288489778728847, local class serialVersionUID = -115879962237199703
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(SerializationHelper.java:278)
at weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(SerializationHelper.java:263)
at featureExtractor.Classify.main(Classify.java:72)
at featureExtractor.Addmood.main(Addmood.java:62)
at featureExtractor.FeaturesExtractor.main(FeaturesExtractor.java:315)
at ui.Test$2$1.run(Test.java:184)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Have no idea whatsoever this is in first line error, also cannot comprehend why it says "unknown source".

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb with this kind of stack trace is to look at the first line of the stack trace that relates to one of YOUR files.  In this case, I'm guessing that's featureExtractor/Classify.java and the problem is on line 72.

Comment: Ya exactly. I still can't figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: This is the problematic line maybe? "Classifier cls = (Classifier)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(curDir+"/src/resources/MetaBag.model");"

Comment: Quite likely.  The message indicates that there's a class which has changed between when you serialised the content of that file (MetaBag.model) and when you're trying to deserialise it.  I'm not sure which class, but maybe `Bagging` in the weka library.  But whichever class it is, you need to save and read the same version of it.  Looks like the weka library isn't particularly backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

[Weka-Android for Weka 3.8.1](https://github.com/MeiyappanKannappa/Weka-Android).

You can successfully load a .model file save using Weka 3.8.6.

This solved the model loading problem due to UUID mismatch.